# Silverlight and desktop drag and drop

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

Is there, in silverlight, the ability to drag and drop files from the desktop into the browser?  I seem to remember seeing something about it being a feature in silverlight 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked into this recently, and based on a post from a Silverlight MVP in the following thread, Silverlight 3 **does not support** file system drag and drop.

http://betaforums.silverlight.net/forums/t/117317.aspx?PageIndex=1

It appears Silverlight 4 now supports this:

http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/silverlight-4-beta-videos/silverlight-controls-drop-targets/

Comment: Bah, I have wasted an entire bike ride home planning a cool application.  Thanks

Comment: This is now available in Silverlight 4: http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/silverlight-4-beta-videos/silverlight-controls-drop-targets/

Answer (score 0):

You can Drag and drop from desktop in a silverlight 4 and above application. Check "Require Elevated permissions" in silverlight project properties and using drop event of silverlight datagrid one can handle the drag and drop from desktop in a silverlight datagrid.

```
private void DocumentsDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
  {
e.Handled = true;

var point = e.GetPosition(null);
var dataGridRow = ExtractDataGridRow(point);
if(dataGridRow !=null)
{.....
 }

var droppedItems = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop) as      FileInfo[];
if (droppedItems != null)
     {
        var droppedDocumentsList = new List<FileInfo>();

        foreach (var droppedItem in droppedItems)
        {
            if ((droppedItem.Attributes & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory)
            {
                var directory = new DirectoryInfo(droppedItem.FullName);
                droppedDocumentsList.AddRange(directory.EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
            }
            else
            {
                droppedDocumentsList.Add(droppedItem);
            }
        }

        if (droppedDocumentsList.Any())
        {
            ProcessFiles(droppedDocumentsList);
        }
        else
        {
            DisplayErrorMessage("The selected folder is empty.");
        }
    }
 }
```

Set AllowDrop =true; in xaml for the datagrid. From the DragEventArgs extract the information as FileInfo Object.
I am not sure about this working with Silverlight 3 application